# Unexpected runtime error

Tags: optimization, gurobi, constraint-programming, logical-constraints, ampl

I have a model that contains the sets (both ordered and Days also circular): Days and Personnel, and I'm trying to make a restriction run exaclty once per Day for every member of Personnel. I'm using AMPL python API and the X-Gurobi solver.

I wrote the restriction, in AMPL, as:

```
subject to Continuos_Free_Days{p in Personnel}: exactly 1 {d in Days} (Free_Day[p,d] = 1 ==> Free_Day[p,next(d,Days)] = 1);
```

But, when I try to solve the model I get and exception raised at the terminal

```
Warning:
        Error executing "solve" command:
        
                Bug: unexpected type 0x9a0c in lsimplify()
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "~/OptimizationMainProject/MainDev/K_Personnel/kopt.py", line 30, in <module>
        ampl.eval("table Assignation_DB OUT 'amplxl': [Personnel,Days,Restaurants,Shifts,Activities],Activated_Assignation;")
      File "~/VirtualEnviroments/pyvenvmacos/lib/python3.10/site-packages/amplpy/ampl.py", line 265, in eval
        self._impl.eval(statements)
    RuntimeError: Unexpected end of file while reading AMPL output.
    Usually this is caused by the termination of the underlying AMPL interpreter.
```

If I remove said constraint, the program runs smoothly and gets an optimal solution. Up until now, I have never got an exception like this one and every other project I'm currently working on runs smoothly also (none of them contains a restriction using the exactly operator).

Does anyone know why is this exception being raised? Is there any other way I could rewrite the constraint to solve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think you want ==> here, since `Free_Day[p,d] = 1 ==> Free_Day[p,next(d,Days)] = 1` is satisfied anytime `Free_Day[p,d] = 0`. Do you maybe instead want this?

```
subject to Continuous_Free_Days{p in Personnel}: 
   exactly 1 {d in Days} (Free_Day[p,d] = 1 and Free_Day[p,next(d,Days)] = 1);
```

If that still gives trouble, you could also try

```
subject to Continuous_Free_Days2{p in Personnel}: 
   count {d in Days} (Free_Day[p,d] = 1 and Free_Day[p,next(d,Days)] = 1) = 1;
```

If you can't get any of these to work, then you're seeing a more general bug. You can report it by sending a minimal example to support@ampl.com, and the developers will get a fix out pretty quickly. In the mean time, I expect someone will suggest a linearization of this constraint.